# Fabricjs canvas bigger than parent, how do I achieve this?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm new to fabricjs, and I'm trying to achieve the following: have a canvas that is a specific size (let's say 600px) but on the browser it should display smaller visually (let's say 300px).

When I download it as png image, it should be 600px wide, even when on screen its size, visually, is 300px

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/82av0coh/1/

```
<div style="width:300px">
     <canvas id="mycanvas" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

As you can see, the canvas is set to be 600px, the parent 300px but the canvas extends instead of resizing (which is what I'd like to achieve).

I'd also like to keep the aspect ratio visually.

Not sure if I can achieve this with pure css, or I need to use fabricjs functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to control the size of the canvas relative to the div size, I think my code can help you with your question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #testBlock {
            width: 300px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        #myCanvas {
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testBlock">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600"></canvas>
   </div>

   <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
        });

        const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                const { width, height } = entry.contentRect;
                console.log(`Width: ${width}px, Height: ${height}px`);
                // The height of the parent is not specified, so the height of the parent will be the same as that of canvas
                canvas.setHeight(height);
                canvas.setWidth(width / 2);
            });
        });

        observer.observe(document.getElementById("testBlock"));
        //document.getElementById('testBlock').setAttribute("style","width:900px");
        //document.getElementById('testBlock').style.width = "900px";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to resize the canvas but want to resize the image, try zooming the canvas or scale the image, I think you'll find the proper methods in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Basically I want to have a canvas that is 600px in width, but visually, for the website visitor, it is 300px. When downloaded as png, it should be 600px (although, again, on the website it is 300px wide); same way as if you have an image that is 600px wide but set the width to be 300px; the image is still 600px but looks like 300px. I am new to frabricjs so not sure if there is a way to "resize" visually quickly, or I need to go element by element resizing what is needed somehow. Thanks!